# Converting clob from oracle to string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am oracle technical Consultant, newbie in asp.net.

How to convert clob output from Oracle Procedure to string in .net application form?

Below is the code, which works fine for Oracle Varchar2 to string c#.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Configuration;

public void SoapRequest_api(string mode1)
{

    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Mobile"].ConnectionString);
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "APPS.P_SOAP_WEBSERVICE.xxstatistics_p";

    OracleParameter soap_request = new OracleParameter(":P_xml", OracleDbType.Clob);
    soap_request.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

    OracleParameter msg = new OracleParameter(":p_msg", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 200);
    msg.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

    OracleParameter refno = new OracleParameter(":p_SitRefNo", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 200);
    refno.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

    OracleParameter mode = new OracleParameter(":p_SitTransCode", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 200);


    mode.Value = mode1;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(mode);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(soap_request);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(msg);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(refno);



    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    try
    {
        int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        string status = msg.Value.ToString();
        string refno_output = refno.Value.ToString();
        con.Close();
        if (status == "S")
        {
            string output = System.Convert.ToString(soap_request.Value);
            this.textBox2.Text = refno_output;
            SOAP_Request(Convert.ToString(soap_request.Value));
        }
        else
        {
            //curuser = null;
            //return false;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(refno.Value.ToString()+"->"+ System.Convert.ToString(soap_request.Value));
    }
    catch (OracleException ex)
    {
        string temp = ex.Message;
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that `ToString()` method just enough? If the CLOB data stored as byte array, just remember what kind of encoding you're using and put `GetString()` instead.

Comment: I have had issues in the past with Oracle where it doesn't use the name to map the parameters, but explicitly the sequence in which they are added to the collection - may not apply here but worth checking the sequence?  You are defining them in a different order to adding them.